# Canvas API disconnect arc from the path's latest point

Tags: canvas, path, automatic-ref-counting, point

An arc draws a line from the starting angle to the previous point on the path

```
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(200,200);
ctx.arc(300, 300, 40, 0, Math.PI, false);
ctx.stroke();
```

[image]

Moving to the point and drawing arc from there give the same result

```
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(200,200);
ctx.moveTo(300, 300);
ctx.arc(300, 300, 40, 0, Math.PI, false);
ctx.stroke();
```

[image]

How to disconnect arc from the path's latest point?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the latest point on the circumference of the arc did the work

```
const startingAngle = Math.PI*.5;
const radius = 40;
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(200,200);
ctx.moveTo(300 + Math.cos(startingAngle) * radius, 300 + Math.sin(startingAngle) * radius);
ctx.arc(300, 300, 40, startingAngle, Math.PI, false);
ctx.stroke();
```